# Java Large String compression safe approach

Tags: java, web-services

For a large string size ~15k, is any java recommended string compression and decompression techniques that are safe to implement.
The gzip format gives junk characters during compression and will it get corrupted when sent in the HTTP soap request. Please advise.

Comment: If you compress the data you have to send it as binary data.

Comment: The requirement is current string is large and it has to be compressed back to string. Does Base64, utf-8, uft-16, ISO-8859-1 encoding approaches can be used & what is the safe way to accomplish this? As said is it only recommended to convert string to byte for compression in java?

Comment: If you have to use soap see if you find it is possible to send binary data in soap (without the solution being encoding the data in Base64 which, not exactly, but will revert the compression process)

Comment: Note that HTTP itself allows for compressed Content-Encodings.  See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.11.

Answer (score 1):

When you zip the text is not any more responding to an encoding as ASCII, UTF, or any other.

The compression will create a new table of conversion between characters and bits (not bytes). One byte could represent less than a character, one character, or more than one character.

The goal of compression is to represent the most repeated characters with the less amount of bits.

Once "compacted" the bytes may overlap with control characters, this why they are a pain to transmit as text.

When you don't have an alternative and have send something which is in binary format over http for example, you do the other way round, you take the bits and add extra bits to bring the binary data into the ASCII range, for example enconding in Base64.

That is why if you first remove extra bits by compressing, and after that you add bits to encode Base64, you might better off sending the original file as it is.

This is the reason why I sugested to send the data in binary format, of see if soap has any alternative to send binary data that doesn't imply reverting the compression process.

Comment: ok. From java coding best practise,  In case the size of string has to be reduced from being larger to lesser along with security that same text cannot be shown such as bank card details, is compression(gzip or any other if available) or encryption(aes,rsa etc) technique better?. which is preferred and why?

Comment: They are two different things: compression = transmit same info with less data. And encryption = make the info unreadable to people withouht the decryption key. For security questions I sugest you asking in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be clear -> I need to encrypt a String to String; it's should have encryption with result String that is smaller. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think you will find a way to do that. The serious encryption algorithms also deliver binary data. And as I said before, encoding binary data to String format is acomplished by adding bits which will result in a longer String. Do something. Thnk how would you acomplish something like this doing it manually?

Comment: Thanks Juan for your reply. I just reached out to the forum you suggested for encryption vs compression and they say compression is best for making size smaller. do you have any compression techniques that doesnt give junk characters in the resultant string.